# why I can not add multiple rows to azure table?

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-storage

I try to add multiple rows to azure storage: I make a report and add it to the azure table, but it add only the last row, I think it replaces it.

```
public void StoreReport()
{
    try
    {
        var timeStamp = DateTime.Now;
        var logsWithError = new List<ReportItem>();

        foreach (var testCategory in Logs)
        {
            foreach (var testItem in Logs[testCategory.Key])
            {
                if (testItem.Value.Any(x => x.LogType == LogType.Error))
                {
                    var reports = testItem.Value.Select(x => new ReportItem()
                    {
                        PartitionKey = timeStamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                        RowKey = testCategory.Key,
                        TestItem = testItem.Key,
                        TestRunStatus = x.LogType.ToString(),
                        TestRunStatusDetail = x.Message,
                        LogTimeStamp = x.TimeStamp
                    });
                    logsWithError.AddRange(reports);
                }
            }
        }

        azureService.AddToAzureTable(logsWithError);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

public async Task AddToAzureTable(List<ReportItem> items)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccountConnectionString);
    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        await table.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(item));
    }
}
```

Comment: You could share the solution in reply and accpet it as answer. Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

Since `AddToAzureTable` is an `async` method, you will have to `await` the execution of it. Please try by changing following line of code:

```
azureService.AddToAzureTable(logsWithError);
```

to

```
await azureService.AddToAzureTable(logsWithError);
```

You will need to make `StoreReport` and other upstream methods async as well.

Comment: thanks for respoding but it did not work, in this line: public async Task AddToAzureTable(List<ReportItem> items) , I have all the logs in item, so the problem is just for adding in table, when I change  InsertOrReplace() to Insert(), it just insert first row.

Comment: ok, I got the problem, it was because of PartitionKey, I was setting it with time, so it was not unique.

Comment: You could use ID instead of time, it would be okay.